# specs2: Tag specification/individual test and exclude it from running using sbt

Tags: sbt, specs2

I need to skip specifications and individual tests while running my test suite. 
Here's an example such test:

```
package models

import org.specs2.mutable._
import org.specs2.runner._

class SlowTaggedSpecification extends Specification{
  "SLOW_SPEC" should {
    "BAD!! Not Skipped" in {
      "axbcd" must find( "bc".r )
    }
  } section( "SLOW_SPEC" )
}

class SlowFastTaggedSpecification extends Specification{
  "SLOW_FAST_SPEC" should {
    "run fast test" in {
      "axbcd" must find( "bc".r )
    } section( "FAST_TEST" )

    "SLOW_TEST should be skipped (BAD!! NOT Skipped)" in {
      "axbcd" must find( "bc".r )
    } section( "SLOW_TEST" )
  } section( "SLOW_FAST_SPEC" )
}
```

I need to skip `SLOW_SPEC` (entire spec) and `SLOW_TEST` (indvidual test only). 
My build.sbt is:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

libraryDependencies += "org.specs2" %% "specs2" % "2.3.12" % "test"
```

When I run the following command line:

```
sbt '~testOnly models.* -- -l SLOW_SPEC'
sbt '~testOnly models.* -- -l SLOW_TEST'
```

none of the tests gets skipped. May I know how do I exclude a specification and an individual test using tags? Also, what would be the sbt syntax if I weren't using `testOnly` , but `test`?

```
sbt '~test -- -l SLOW_SPEC'
```

causes sbt to complain. My sbt version is 0.13.5

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command line argument to exclude tags is

```
sbt> ~testOnly models.* -- exclude SLOW_SPEC
```

If you want to exclude tags when using the `test` command you need to use `Test.Arguments` in your `build.sbt` file:

```
testOptions in Test += Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.Specs2, "exclude", "SLOW_SPEC")
```

If you want to specifically run a SLOW_SPEC test, then use the following:

```
sbt 'set testOptions in Test := Seq()' '~testOnly models.SlowTaggedSpecification'
```

Comment: Thank you very much! 
For posterity: to skip multiple tags, separate using commas: 
`sbt '~testOnly models.* -- exclude SLOW_FAST_SPEC,SLOW_SPEC'`

Comment: So the confusion about the syntax occurred because my project also included scalatest which doesn't like this particular command line syntax.
Btw, if I exclude "SLOW_SPEC" in build.sbt using the statement given, then there is absolutely no way for me to run it, even if I were to use 
sbt '~testOnly models.* -- include SLOW_SPEC'.

Comment: You can remove the `testOptions` setting from your sbt session by doing `set testOptions in Test := Seq()` (or something similar).

Comment: To be more specific in removing only the option that exclude such a test from running, this can be used: `sbt 'set testOptions in Test := (testOptions in Test).value.filterNot( x => x == Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.Specs2, "exclude", "SLOW_SPEC" ) )'  '~testOnly models.*'`